# Grep for a line containing only 5 or 6 numbers

Tags: grep

How would you grep for a line containing only 5 or 6 numbers? Something like this.

case 1  (has leading space)

```
           10      2       12      1       13
```

case 2  (no leading space)

```
   1       2       3       4       5        6
```

I thought something like this would work.

```
grep -E '[0-9]{5}'
```

Comment: Is this your homework?

Comment: @WarrenYoung no. I'm just trying to filter through massive debugging files.

Comment: @cokedude Can you post some more example lines, preferably a representative sample as to what should and should not match?

Comment: @muru yours grabs everything I want. It also creates a line separator from my original numbers which makes it even more readable than I expected.

Comment: @cokedude what about if line contained more than six numbers in it `1       2       3       4       5        6       7`? Should this line must present in output or not?

Comment: An example doesn't make a requirement specification. There are 6 triodecimal numbers in `abc` (`a`, `b`, `c`, `ab`, `bc` and `abc`). Does that count?

Comment: I was looking for a related regex query and found this helpful one: https://stackoverflow.com/a/29416965/470749

Answer (score 9):

`grep -E '[0-9]{5}'` is looking for numbers with at least 5 digits. What you need is 5 numbers with at least one digit:

```
grep -E '[0-9]+([^0-9]+[0-9]+){4}'
```

- `[0-9]+` - a number of at least one digit
- `[^0-9]+[0-9]+` - a number with at least one digit, preceded by at least one non-digit character. We then repeat this 4 times to get 5 numbers separated by non-digits.
- If the requirement is exactly 5, you might want to surround this regex with `[^0-9]` so that the entire line is matched (with the anchors, of course).
- Depending on what you want here (does `1,2,3,4,6` qualify?), you might look at other separators. For example, a proper scientific notation real number would look like: `[+-]?(([0-9]+(\.[0-9]+)?)|([0-9]?\.[0-9]+))([eE][+-][0-9]+)?` So separators may not include `.`, `e`, etc. They may only be whitespace, as `mikeserv` notes. Or they maybe commas, if it's a CSV record. Or depending on the locale, a comma would be the decimal separator. Vary `[^0-9]` as per your need.

Comment: I don't have any commas between my numbers. I just have a bunch of space between my numbers. I did make a couple of trivial tweaks to also grep for fault and Fault. `grep -E '[0-9]+([^0-9]+[0-9]+){4}|fault|Fault' `

Comment: yours works the I want. I just added more description to clarify for cuonglm.

Comment: @muru this returns  `1  2  3  4  5  6  7` and `111 222 333 444 A555` as result but those are not actually contain **only**  5 or 6 numbers.

Comment: @KasiyA, see the 3rd bullet-point in the answer.

Comment: @KasiyA if you insist: `grep -P '^\s*\d+(\s+\d+){4,5}\s*$'`

Comment: ^^ That command is what OP wants. "Grep for a line containing only 5 or 6 numbers"

Comment: @KasiyA Technically, what OP wants is already posted in [the first comment](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/171399/grep-for-a-line-containing-only-5-or-6-numbers/171403?noredirect=1#comment282946_171403).

Answer (score 3):

I would go with something a little more powerful than `grep`. This can do it in perl:

```
perl -ne 'print if s/\d+/$&/g == 5' your_file
```

The regex substitution replaces all groups of one or more digits (`\d+`) with themselves (`$&`): it does nothing. It is used merely for side effect since the `s///` operator returns the number of times it managed to substitute for its regex. Thus, the line is printed only if `s///` found 5 groups of digits.

Comment: This will match line like `1a 1 1 1 1`

Comment: @cuonglm I thankfully don't have any numbers like that. All of my important numbers are on there own line and separated by space.

Comment: @josephr Can you please explain how yours works? It doesn't grab this massive list of numbers `1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11`, but it does grab this `1 2 3 4 5 6`. It does chop off the 1 though.

Answer (score 2):

Another `perl`:

```
$ perl -MList::Util=first -Tnle '
  s/^\s+|\s+$//g;
  @e = split /\s+/;
  print if @e == 5 || @e == 6 and !first {/\D/} @e;
' file
10      2       12      1       13
```

**Explanation**

- `s/^\s+|\s+$//g` trim the line.
- `@e = split /\s+/` split the line into array `@e`.
- We will print the line if:

  - array `@e` contains 5 or 6 elements.
  - And None of its elements contain non-digit characters (`\D` match non-digit characters).

Comment: How does it work?

Comment: @muru: Added explanation.

Comment: @cuonglm is \D wrong? I wanted it to match digits. Right now it doesn't print anything.

Comment: @cokedude: Is your input contain leading spaces?

Comment: @cuonglm sorry I wasn't clear. The 5 word lines have several leading spaces. The 6 word lines have no leading space. And can you add one easy piece to also match fault or Fault?

Answer (score 2):

```
awk '{l=$0; n = gsub(/[0-9]+/, "", l)}; n == 5 || n == 6'
```

(same principle as in [Joseph's answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/171401))

Comment: I take it the principle is the same as in [this answer](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/171401/70524)?

Comment: it matches with `4a` too..

Comment: @JigarGandhi, yes, nobody said it shouldn't or how the numbers may or may not be separated.

Answer (score 2):

```
grep -E '^(\s*[0-9]+\s+){4,5}[0-9]+\s*$'
```

Answer (score 0):

A way with awk that is customisable for different numbers of fields.
Also whitespace does not matter.

```
awk 'NF~/^(5|6)$/{x=0;for(i=1;i<=NF;i++)x+=($i~/^[0-9]+$/)}x==NF' file
```

This checks the number of fields is 5 or 6 although more numbers of fields could be added if your requirements ever change.

Then it sets a counter to 0

Then loops checking each field is a number and if it is adds 1 to the counter

If the counter equals the number of fields it prints the line.

#### example

`input`

```
  1       2       3       4       5        6
        2       3       4       5        6
3       4       5        6
blah  1       2       3       4       5
      4       3324       4       53        6
```

`output`

```
  1       2       3       4       5        6
        2       3       4       5        6
      4       3324       4       53        6
```

Comment: why does it print out a bunch of x's? The very last line is right but the rest is just x's.

Comment: What do you mean ? It shouldn't print any `x`s

Comment: http://www.pixhost.org/show/1864/24202911_awk_test.jpg

Comment: @cokedude, whats the input and can you show me how you executed the command, also it shouldn't make any difference but check the version of awk you are using using `awk --version`

Comment: Is gnu awk 3.0.4 to old to do what I want? Its the awk that came with git bash.

Comment: @cokedude no that should work fine, i honestly can't see any reason it would print x's, are there any x's in the file ? Did you c+p the command or is it possible theres a typo ? Is it in single or double quotes ?

Comment: yes there are a TON of x's in my file. I have tried both of these with no luck. `awk 'NF==5||NF==6 {x=0;for(i=1;i<=NF;i++)x+=($i~/^[0-9]+$/)}x==NF' test` and `awk 'NF~/^(5|6)$/{x=0;for(i=1;i<=NF;i++)x+=($i~/^[0-9]+$/)}x==NF' test`.

Comment: @cokedude does it work with example that i provided ?

Answer (score 0):

I know I have not solved  using `sed` or `awk` or any of `shell` commands, However `tcl` did work out well.

I have kept the script simple and user friendly. elements like `4a abc` etc will be taken care

### command

```
script.tcl file
```

### Script

```
#!/usr/bin/tclsh

if {$argv == ""} {
        puts "please enter the arguement"
        exit ;
}

set tar_fl [lindex $argv 0]
if {![file exists $tar_fl]} {
        puts "$tar_fl doesnot exist"
        exit ;
}

set flptr [open $tar_fl r]

while {[gets $flptr line] >=0 } {
        if {[llength $line] !=5} {continue ;}
        if {[llength $line ] == 5} {
                if {[lsearch -regexp  $line {[^0-9]}]> -1} {continue;}
                puts $line
        }

}

close $flptr
```

### Output

```
           10      2       12      1       13
1       2       3       4       5
```